# How do I apply latex paint over oil based paint?

Tags: painting, repainting

I sure hope someone can help me. I decided to paint my kitchen which I was not aware of but had been painted by the previous owner with an oil based paint. I painted over that with 3 coats of latex trying to get an even finish. With no luck, I went to our local paint store and the guy said to use a primer. So I got a latex primer and put 2 coats on it and still no luck! I spot tested it and the paint still is not going on smoothly. Should I have used an oil based primer? Went to another paint store and was told the only way to fix it is sand down to the original and put an oil based primer over it. Needless to say, this will take forever! Now I am to the point of just putting paintable wallpaper over it but am afraid it won't stick. Can someone please help me?

Also, I am pretty sure that the previous owner may have painted over wallpaper

Comment: I am certain you are not the first person in this position.  Call the customer service number of the manufacturer of the first layer of paint that you applied, and be ready to answer questions like 'how did you prep the wall for the first coat'?

Comment: When you say "not smoothly", do yo mean the paint is separating or is lumpy?

Answer (score 2):

There are two critical steps in prepping kitchen walls.

**Clean and degloss**

Cleaning is critical:  [TSP or TSP substitute](http://www.savogran.com/heavy-duty-cleaning.html).

Deglossing: either light sanding (120 grit) or a chemical deglosser

Once a surface is deglossed, it should be primed, especially if going from one paint type to another.

A deglossed oil undercoat can be primed with a **latex primer**.  Either oil or latex can then be used as a topcoat.

A deglossed oil undercoat can be primed with a **oil primer**.  Either oil or latex can then be used as a topcoat.

It is better to stick within families of paint types, if you can, but going back and forth between types is possible with primers.

At this stage in coating, I'd let everything dry for a week, then sand lightly.  If the previous layers are adhering, then proceed with latex primer, latex topcoat.

If,, however, they are sloughing or chipping or you can easily pull a layer off if you leave painters tape on overnight (and then pull it off), then you must sand down to the **last well adhered layer** and then repaint.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just lightly sand the surface to degloss.  Clean it throughly with krud kleaner (I think that is spelled right) you do not need to remove all the old paint. just ruck up the top layer.  Use a good latex primer (dont use an oil based primer if your going to paint with latex) Then paint.